# splitting a string in a column and adding duplicate rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

Suppose I have the following dataframe, called 'example':

```
a <- c("rs123|rs246|rs689653", "rs9753", "rs00334")
b <- c(1,2,9)
c <- c(234534523, 67345634, 536423)

example <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

I want the dataframe to look like this:

```
                a b         c
            rs123 1 234534523
            rs246 1 234534523
         rs689653 1 234534523
           rs9753 2  67345634
          rs00334 9    536423
```

Where if we split column a on the `|` delimiter, the other columns are duplicated.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `separate_rows` from the `tidyr` package (part of the `tidyverse` package).

```
library(tidyverse)

example2 <- example %>%
  separate_rows(a)
example2
#          a b         c
# 1    rs123 1 234534523
# 2    rs246 1 234534523
# 3 rs689653 1 234534523
# 4   rs9753 2  67345634
# 5  rs00334 9    536423
```

Here is one way to convert `example2` back to the original format.

```
example3 <- example2 %>%
  group_by(b, c) %>%
  summarize(a = str_c(a, collapse = "|")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(names(example2)) %>%
  mutate(a = factor(a)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

identical(example, example3)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks! Just for completeness and curiosity's sale, lets say I wanted to go from 'example2' back to something like 'example'.  What's the best way to do that?